# Getting license details in Artifactory REST API

Tags: rest, artifactory

I would like to get **Long Name**, **URL**, and **Notes** field values from Artifactory REST API. These fields are available when I'm editing from the web app.

When I hit the [License Search API](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-LicenseSearch), I'm not getting these fields. Is there any API that I can use to get more details?

**License Search API result**

```
{"uri": "http://localhost:8080/artifactory/api/storage/libs-release-local/org/acme/lib/ver/lib-ver.jar",
"license": "lgplv2",
"found": "",
"status": "approved"}
```

**Webapp showing field values**

[image: Artifactory Edit License]

Answer (score 1):

There is no 'official' REST API call for that.

First of all, [a feature request](http://issues.jfrog.org/) is welcome.

Second, you can create such an endpoint yourself by implementing [an `execution` user plugin](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/User+Plugins#UserPlugins-Executions). It will, probably, require a usage of internal APIs, so be prepared to test and maintain it after upgrades.
[Here's a good example](https://github.com/JFrogDev/artifactory-user-plugins/blob/master/governance/discoverLicenseAndPerventUnapproved.groovy#L55) to get you started (also uses the exact service you'll need).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, and as of Artifactory 5.4.6, there is no official API to retrieve global license information (i.e. what is shown in the *Admin > Configuration > Licenses page*).

If you are ready to rely on undocumented API, you could call directly the "License export" web service. It is undocumented / not public and outputs XML but that seems to work well enough.

```
curl -u "admin:password" -X GET "http://yourartifactory/artifactory/ui/licenseexport"
```

will output

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<licenses>
  <licenses>
    <license>
      <name>AFL-3.0</name>
      <longName>The Academic Free License 3.0</longName>
      <url>http://www.opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php</url>
      <regexp>((.*)(academic)(.*)|(AFL)+(.*))(3)(.*)</regexp>
      <approved>false</approved>
      <unknown>false</unknown>
      <validLicense>false</validLicense>
      <found>false</found>
      <notFound>false</notFound>
      <notSearched>false</notSearched>
    </license>
    <license>
    [...]
    </license>
  </licenses>
</licenses>
```

By combining the outputs from licenseexport and the licensesearch, you could script whatever you need...